# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'RxPMIS.DSet01.tbSystemUsersDataTable'

Tags: sql, datatable, dataset

Okay I may be asking this the wrong way, however simply put:

I am using tableAdapters in my dataset (DSet01) and have several Fill / Get data statements that I would like to eliminate by just passing on an SQL statement to populate the main dataset  e.g. Main Table Adapter:= "tbSystemUsers" which has a general "Fill" "Get"...i.e. "`Select * from tbSystemUsers`" ... and instead of adding another query in this tableAdapter I want to create an SQL statement such as "`Select * from tbSystemUsers WHERE (userId = @userID)`".

And return the dataset which I can view on my data-grid.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't have asked this question here: simply put the Project I inherited from a work colleague initially used a auto generated table adapters in its data-set designer. So this time around when i defined my classes, it fails because the GetData containers have already been define.

Either remove the table adapters class Or initialize my output to the same 
existing one as in:

```
        psmDS02.tbIssuesDataTable myIssues = new psmDS02.tbIssuesDataTable();
        int postID = this.psmDS02.tbIssues[tbIssuesBindingSource.Position].issuesID;
        myIssues = (psmDS02.tbIssuesDataTable) PsDataLayer.cls_0_gridsData.Issues_GetData_ID(postID);
```

The conversion is in the third line. Thanks